# How to iterate over each `numpy.float16`

Tags: python, numpy

For a certain task, I have too many repeated calls to a complex function, call it `f(x)` where `x` is float. I do not have very large floats and not too much precision is required, so I thought why not use a lookup table for f(x), where x is a float16, maximum size of lookup table is (2**16). I was planning on making a small python demo using `np.float16`. I am a bit stuck on how to iterate over range of all floats. In `C/C++`, I would have used an `uint16_t`, kept incrementing it. How do I create this table using python ?

Comment: Do you need to pre-compute all of the return values, i.e. does your code pass each value to the complex function at least twice? If not, memoization may be a more performant solution. Take a look at `functools.lru_cache` if this is the case.

Comment: @MichaelRuth, yeah, I need to precompute value for each float. LRU or any caching strategy is not a good idea as any `x` is likely to be called and not in any order. I want something like a `constexpr` lookup table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate all the possible values using `arange` and then reinterpret the values as `float16` values using `view`. Here is an example:

```py
np.arange(65536, dtype=np.uint16).view(np.float16)
```

This should give you all possible `float16` values. Note that many are NaN values.

Comment: Okay. I believe NaN values will be those with exponent 11111 and 00000 ? Also, when I have a float `x`, how do I get corresponding index in this table ?

Comment: With the exponent 11111 but not 00000 (whatever the sign). You can find more information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) about this. For finding floats, it is not easy. One solution is to sort the table and do a dichotomy. Another faster solution could be to transform a float into a `np.float16`, then view it as `np.uint16` to finally use it as an index (`O(1)`).

Comment: The 2048 `-inf`,`+inf` and `nan` values are contained within the ranges `[0x7c00 : 0x8000]` and `[0xfc00 : 0x10000]`, i.e. `[(1<<15) - (1<<10): 1<<15]` and `[-(1<<10):]`.